# Long visitor visa for France is refused

Tags: france

Despite of hiring a very reputed emigration/visa agent (from France), my long visitor visa (was refused by consulate. The reason of refusal was :reason of stay is unreliable". Surely this is very shocking when it affects all your long term plans; and you have put everything in order along with school admission documents for children and very solid work and bank profiles.

While third party (TLS contact) accepting application mentioned that it might take 2 to 4 or even 6 weeks for such cases, the decision for my application was taken in merely 3 days without any regard to efforts and preparation gone in it. The same 3rd party (TLS Contact) also mentioned during application that authority speaks English. But when I was called from Consulate (in 2 days), she did not speak any word in English. I was lost before I could say anything and the call was dropped.

Next day I got mail to collect the passport, just to find out that visa was refused- all done in 3 days only for 4 passports, while even a plain schengen visa is issued in 1 week.

Now what are the options I have, as I am very keen to apply for the same visa again. Should I appeal against the decision? Or its not worth it?

The visa type applied was **long Sejour (visitor)**. The children's application was asked to be changed to Student Visa during application from TLS contact. Indian national with sound finance and businesses in multiple countries.

Comment: Could you clarify somewhat? What was the purpose of your stay? Any more details on why you were refused? What is your nationality and background?

Comment: @mts i have tried to fine-tune and update the question. Hope not this make little better now.

Comment: @outflak The EU countries and France allows long visitor visa, which essentially gets you residence once you are in the country. I chose international school.

Comment: It's not clear what your goals are. Are you wanting to immigrate to France? You mentioned school admission documents. For French schools? That's not 'visiting', that's residence. Maybe if you applied for the correct visa type, you would have success. *Edit*: With the extra comments and the edits, the question is clearer. We can offer  advice if you can tell us *'exactly'* why the visa was refused in your post. Even then, my advice would be to address their reasons with proper evidence and apply again.

Comment: @user22132, not all EU countries have such a visa.

Comment: @outflak Confusingly, in France, “visiteur” is the name of all long-stay visas and residence permits that do not fall in any of the specific categories provided by the law. It's perfectly legal to immigrate with one.

Comment: @outflak may be you are right. I meant for Schengen states. I will check again.

Answer (score 3):

Your options are limited:

- Reapplying is unlikely to provide satisfaction, the consulate does not have to provide any justification and can promptly take the same decision. Maybe if your circumstances change and time passes, you would have more luck but I don't see them easily changing their mind. But if anything, that's what I would try, as it is not expensive and could theoretically be granted. This time, you should look for another agent, able to prepare an application in French.
- Appealing is even less likely to help. It takes at least a couple of years and definitely requires someone well-versed in French law. Worse, you have to find some basis to argue that you are entitled to this visa in the first place. Unlike, say, spouse visas, a regular long-stay *visiteur* visa is not something you are entitled to as of right, consulates can legally refuse them without justification and judges have no reason to overturn these decisions. More details on that in [France long stay student visa refused 3 times without any reason by French embassy New Delhi](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9379/france-long-stay-student-visa-refused-3-times-without-any-reason-by-french-embas/9380#9380)

  I actually know someone who did this successfully but it was a very specific case (something akin to a “kafala”, which is not quite an adoption but there is case law in France stating it should be treated like one for visa purposes) and it was not easy, which is why I don't think you should hope an appeal would help in your case.

Your best bet if you really want to come to France is to find another visa category with better prospects but obviously your circumstances do not necessarily fit any other visa category.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helps a lot. My agent was top notch French lawyer firm, who prepared the covering letter in French with detailed justification. I am wondering weather the outcome would be different, if I could have answered the phone call in French!

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helps a lot. My agent was top notch French lawyer firm, who prepared the covering letter in French with detailed justification. I am wondering weather the outcome would be different, if I could have answered the phone call in French!