# France long stay student visa refusals

Tags: france, student-visa, refusal

I have applied three times for a student visa and each time was refused for the same reasons:

- you have not provided sufficient evidence to enable the consular authority that your stay in France for study purpose is not abusive
- you have not provided justification of your stay or unreal

I have booked crous accommodation for 9-months , but I haven't any student loan because I have a sufficient amount to cover all my expenses.

Is a large amount of money put in my account without any explanation creating the problem?

Comment: Do you have an offer of a place to study with a French university?

Comment: You've read this already, but sadly I think this answer is the most relevant to your situation: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/9380/8483

Comment: As explained on the TSE sister site, it sounds as though you may have been [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications) and now have [serial refusals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99216/i-have-been-denied-a-visa-several-times-in-a-row-how-does-one-deal-with-such-se). Continuing to apply to France or to any other Schengen state is unlikely to change the outcome in the short term.

Answer (score 1):

When a Schengen refusal notice contains the reasons as you have stated them (and you were refused for the same on all three occasions), it indicates that the application has serious problems, as determined by the person(s) reviewing it. That, alone, is extremely serious and, after three refusals, it means that they don’t believe you and don’t trust you.

Thus, booking a flat serves no purpose, through the Centre régional des œuvres universitaires et scolaires (CROUS) or any other means. Nor does depositing money for purposes of convincing consular officials of your financial abilities; while not advisable and often one of the reasons for visa refusals, you now have a greater problem.

And, to put it bluntly, if the latest refusal does actually says abusive’ (abuser), it might be unwise to re-apply any time in the near future to France (or perhaps any Schengen country) as you may attract a ban.