# French student visa rejection

Tags: visa, student-visa, study

I am an Indian who was selected into a good French University for sports and tourism. I am going for my masters. But my father is an pensioned retired police officer. He is the sponsor for my studies. We didn't take an educational loan, but my sister took a personal loan for my studies.

Last time my visa was rejected within 3 days. I submitted all the documents, but still I got rejected.

1. Did I get rejected as my sponsor is an pensioned individual?
2. Can I improve my chances for acceptance if I change my sponsor?

Comment: What reason(s) were you given for the refusal? It would help if you posted a copy of the refusal notice, with personal details obscured

Comment: @Traveller Legally, they don't have to give a reason. Typically, they don't because it might give you something to appeal. So why go to the trouble of extra work that could be a source of error when an unmotivated decision is virtually unassailable?

Comment: @Relaxed Ok, I thought they might at least give a proforma response, as they do for short stay questions. But in that case, the question is pretty much unanswerable

Comment: @Traveller Yes that would make sense and for short-stay visas they have to, it's mandated by EU law. Under French law, it's not necessarily the case for long-stay visas, I just realised I wrote [an answer detailing all this](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9379/france-long-stay-student-visa-refused-3-times-without-any-reason-by-french-embas/9380#9380) a long time ago. The question was a bit different but it shows why your options are limited. In practice, it's difficult to know what the problem might and I doubt that changing sponsors would make a difference.

Comment: Actually, double-checking the link I learned that my earlier answer is outdated (and actually became incorrect a mere three weeks after I wrote it). It appears that since November 2016, every refusal does have to be “motivated”. I have no idea how detailed or actionable the justification might be and it remains the case that a student visa is discretionary but you should at least have received some explanation.

Comment: Possible related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11617/france-long-stay-student-visa-refusals?r=SearchResults

Comment: This is the reason for rejection which I recieved from them "Justification of intended stay is not reliable". I even attached the accomodation document which was sent by my university.